# Let $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^4$ and $T(1,-1,3)=(2,0,-2,4)$ , $T(2,1,4)=(3,0,-3,6)$ Show that T is not injective and not surjective (simple)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^4$ and $T(1,-1,3)=(2,0,-2,4)$ , $T(2,1,4)=(3,0,-3,6)$ Show that T is not injective and not surjective

---

I know that the function is not onto because of $dim(kerT)+dim(ImT)=n$ and in order for it to be onto $dim(ImT)=dim( \Bbb R^4)=4$ but it is not possible because $dim(kerT)+4\not=3$ I know that in order to show that it is injective we need to show that $kerT\not=\{0\}$
but how can I show it?
thanks for any tips and hints!

Comment: What happens if you divide both sides by 2 in the first result, and 3 in the second result?

Comment: It's not necessary to show the kernel is non-trivial. As long as you can find two different vectors that map to the same vector you're done.

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta so when i divide the results as you said i get the same result for both of them and as the other comment says if two different vectors map to the same then it is not injective ?

Comment: Exactly! @Adamrk